# Camel upgrade 2.2.0->2.6.0 and now file endpoint doesn't find files (on Linux)

Tags: apache-camel

Upgraded to 2.6.0 (from 2.2.0), and it works fine on Windows.

But on Linux the camel route no longer appears to pickup any files using the file endpoint.

endpoint:

```
<camel:endpoint id="xyzFileEndpoint" uri="{{camel.xyz.file.endpoint}}" />
```

and in property file:

```
camel.xyz.file.endpoint=file:/xyz/datafiles/inbound?maxMessagesPerPoll=3&move=/xyz/datafiles/archive_inbound/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:onlyname}.processed&readLock=rename&filter=#fileFilter&delay=15000
```

Is there any way to turn on debugging so I can see why its not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have narrowed it down to a problem with the fileFilter. FileFilter is checking first character matches [A-Za-z0-9].

On windows first character will = C (c drive).
On linux first character = /